# Can Sorcerers summon elementals?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer

I know that druids/wizards can summon elementals, but can sorcerers summon them without multiclassing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes

When Sorcerers get to 17th level, they have access to the *Wish* spell. This spell can replicate any spell of 8th level or lower, including *Conjure Elemental* and *Conjure Minor Elementals*.

Furthermore, they can be given a **Ring of Spell Storing** which contains one of the Elemental-summoning spells, pre-charged by a Wizard. They will be able to summon the Elemental as if they had cast the spell.

Answer (score 8):

### Yes, with magic items

The DMG has the Bowl of commanding water elementals, Brazier of commanding fire elementals, Censer of controlling air elementals, and the Stone of controlling earth elementals.

Each of these items allows you to summon their respective elemental as if you had cast the *Conjure Elementals* spell.

Of course, one could use *Wish* or any of the other ways to transfer spells, but these items are a more direct way of replicating that ability without using up spell slots.

Answer (score 7):

No, not inherently, or specific to being a sorcerer.

There are magic items that can allow them to summon elementals, but those could equally well apply to any spellcaster class, and have nothing to do with being  sorcerer, per se.  Within the powers of the sorcerer class, there is no provision for summoning or controlling elementals, short of using the Wish spell for that at 17th level plus.

Comment: I can't help but be critical of an answer that says "no, it can't be done except for this one way."  ...Wish is a completely valid answer to this question. (As well as magic items, since "without multiclassing" is the only condition specified.)

Comment: The Wish spell is a caveat to just about ANY "can you do this" question.  And it carries its own hazards and costs.  So even if you can do something by Wish, if that's your only option, it's not a sustainable tactic.  I included it in my answer for completeness, but the real useful answer is still "no", it's not a thing sorcerors get to do as part of their class.

Comment: What hazards and costs?  Using wish to duplicate another spell is the only use that does NOT incur damage or include any DM-introduced risks, it just happens, even bypassing material costs of the spell. ...and how is it not part of the sorcerer class? Its literally a sorcerer spell.

Comment: Mostly having to be 17th level, and use a 9th level spell slot that you can do almost anything with to create a 5th level effect.  It's dumb and inefficient, and (again) the point is that Sorcerors do not have any spells or powers that are actually aimed at doing anything with elementals.